# Nothing happens when clicking on routerLink href in Angular 6.1

Tags: angular, servicestack, asp.net-core-2.1

Nothing happens when I click on the route defined in the following way.

```
<li>
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About Us</a>
</li>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

is in the app.component.html file (which is where the routerlink is)

```
{ path: 'about/', component: AboutComponent }
```

is added to the routes in app.module.ts.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

is imported in the *about.component*.

Is there some obvious thing that I am missing?

Comment: Have you imported RouterModule in your component's module?

Comment: Is this `[routerLink]['/about']"routerLinkActive="active"` a typo only here or also in your code? It should be `[routerLink]="['/about']" routerLinkActive="active"`

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash in your route. It should be: `{ path: 'about', component: AboutComponent } `

Comment: It was like  <li><a class="nav-link" [routerLink] = "['about/']"routerLinkActive="active">About Us</a> </li> in the code.  Just a typo here.  Do I need the RouterModule in every component or just the one where the routes are defined?

Comment: I am not allowed to select this as answered anymore, but you are correct @HarunYılmaz. That worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @AtleKristiansen No worries. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name you are using in app.component.html has a / character.

You have two options

1. (recommended): just delete that character.

   { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
2. Just add it in the routerLink:

   ```
   <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about/" routerLinkActive="active">About Us</a>
   ```